# $\mathbb{F}$ contains a unique subfield of cardinality $p^n$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I'm referring to the[page 197](https://books.google.lk/books?id=wZj3cHoRQywC&pg=PA197&dq=If%20n%20is%20a%20positive%20integer,%20F%20contains%20a%20unique%20subfield%20of%20cardinality&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8hbie0s7RAhUJt48KHUvBCNsQ6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=If%20n%20is%20a%20positive%20integer%2C%20F%20contains%20a%20unique%20subfield%20of%20cardinality&f=false) of the book [Field extension and Galois theory by Julio R. Bastida](http://bookzz.org/s/?q=Field%20extension%20and%20Galois%20theory%20Bastida&yearFrom=&yearTo=&language=&extension=&t=0).

let $\mathbb{P}$ be a prime field with prime characteristic, $p$ and $\mathbb{F}$ be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{P}$.
Then if $n$ is a positive integer, $\mathbb{F}$ contains a unique sub field of cardinality $p^n$.

Can somebody please explain why this happens?
* also notice that being the algebraic closure we can prove $\mathbb{F}$ is infinite and Galois over $\mathbb{K}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field with $p^n$ elements is made up of the roots of $X^{p^n}-X$ which happen to be distinct.

This gives also uniqueness because any element $x$ in a field with $p^n$ elements must satisfy the relation $x^{p^n}=x$.

Comment: Thank you Andrea. 
To make it clear, is it because of the fact that $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed, we consider the above polynomial is seperable (hence distinct roots)?

Comment: @CharithJeewantha: exactly. Since $\Bbb F$ is algebraically closed it must contain **all** the roots of that polynomial. That makes it.